# UK Landside Transit with UK BRP

Tags: uk, transit

this will be a somewhat specific question.

Is it possible for a non-EEA visa national to transit through UK with a valid UK Biometric Residence Permit (BRP)? Like for example, say a visa national student (e.g. Pakistan) has a BRP, but will be flying from Pakistan to France, with a landside transit in the UK. Can this passenger use his UK BRP for a transit reason?

According to UKVI, the alternative UK Visas that could be substituted for a Transit Visa would be:

- an EEA family permit
- a Home Office travel document, for example you’re a refugee or stateless person
- a Standard Visitor visa
- a Marriage Visitor visa

it does not say a UK BRP. That's why I wondered if it is possible or not?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A residence permit indicates that the bearer has permission to reside somewhere.  *Your* biometric residence permit indicates that *you* have permission to reside in the United Kingdom.

Because you have permission to reside in the United Kingdom, you may enter the UK for as long (or short) a period as you like within the validity of the permit.  If the permit is valid, you may use it for transit.

As noted in another answer, a permit that is nominally valid may be invalidated by a change of circumstances, so you must take this into account.  In particular, if you have completed or abandoned your studies in the UK, you should not rely on the BRP.

Answer (score 1):

If your circumstances that your BRP is based on has not significantly changed, you enter as a returning resident for your ongoing purpose (e.g. studying). Then you are simply going on a trip shortly after.

Alternatively, you would still be allowed landside transfer based on the exception for holders of a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country (that is, pending finalization of Brexit).

This is also confirmed by Timatic

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Nationals of Pakistan transiting through
> London: Gatwick (LGW) or Heathrow (LHR) with a confirmed onward ticket
> for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must:
>
> - have a common format residence permit issued by United Kingdom, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Nationals of Pakistan making a landside transit with a confirmed
> onward ticket for a flight to a third country that departs before
> 23:59 the next day. They must:
>
> - have a common format residence permit issued by United Kingdom, and
> - clear immigration, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.